# Crear un array desde un fichero

Tags: array, c

¿Cómo se puede crear un vector con números que se encuentran en un fichero, sin conocer a priori la cantidad de números que hay?

Mi objetivo es la formación de un vector con los datos del fichero, pero una formación dinámica.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin conocer a priori los datos deberás usar una estructura de tipo lista enlazada, en lugar de vector. A menos que quieras recorrer primero el fichero para contar cuántos hay y luego usar ese número para crear un array dinámico con `malloc()`. Esta opción es mucho más sencilla que la lista enlazada, ocupa menos memoria y es más eficiente para recorrer después los elementos. También podrías crear con `malloc()` un vector inicial y si ves que se queda pequeño a medida que lees, aumentarle el tamaño con `realloc()`

Comment: Entonces, que debo leer el fichero en primer lugar, contando cuantos números hay y crear el vector con malloc?

Comment: Soy nuevo en c, como podría leer los numeros en cada linea, lo intento realizar con fgets pero me salta error al compilar

Comment: pon por favor el código que has hecho

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo tu punto, si te exigen que lo crees de manera dinámica puede hacer lo que te comentaron con el malloc y realloc puedes ver exactamente que hacen esas funciones en [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/), recuerda utilizar correctamente el free para que no te llene la memoria al probar.

Te dejo una implementación que funciona, tambien depende como sean los datos que te piden, el mio es un archivo .txt que tienen numeros y caracteres de nueva linea, por lo que la funcion fgets cumple con lo que debe y utilizo atoi para la conversión a entero. Como te dije antes no es la forma de hacerlo dinámico ese es un detalle que te solicitan pero este código funciona correctamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FALSE -99
int main(){
   FILE *forRead;
   int futurosNumeros[30];
   int i=0;
   cerar(futurosNumeros);
   //Abro archivo para lectura
   forRead=fopen("hola.txt","r");
   //Creo un char como buffer
   char numero[100];
   //Creo un char * porque eso devuelve la funcion fgets
   char* charAsterisco;

   //Ciclo para leer todooo lo del archivo
   do{
       //Leo y guardo en charAsterisco
       charAsterisco=fgets(numero,100,forRead);
       if(charAsterisco!=NULL)
           //Convierto a entero
           futurosNumeros[i]=atoi(charAsterisco);   
       i++;
   }while(charAsterisco!=NULL);
   futurosNumeros[i-1]=FALSE;

   //Compruebo si convirtio todo a int con printf imprimiendolo
   for(i=0;futurosNumeros[i]!=FALSE;i++)
       printf("%d -", futurosNumeros[i]);   
   fclose(forRead);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Si el programa funciona bien, el valor de retorno de `main` debe ser `0` no `1`

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo se puede crear un vector con números que se encuentran en un fichero, sin conocer a priori la cantidad de números que hay?

No se puede.

---

Tienes dos alternativas:

1. **Pre-procesado de datos**: Puedes analizar el archivo al completo, contar los elementos del mismo, reservar memoria y acto seguido volver a procesar el archivo para guardar los datos.
2. **Usa una estructura dinámica**: Olvida el uso de vectores, usa una lista enlazada. Por desgracia C no dispone de librerías estándar de contenedores, por lo que deberás usar una librería externa (como [sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/)) o desarrollar tu propia lista enlazada.

¿Por qué no considero el uso de `malloc` y `realloc` ([sugerido por Oscar Gonzalez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/236858/2742)) como solución? Porque alojar y realojar memoria es un proceso altamente costoso que debe ser evitado a toda costa a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario; es probable<sup>1</sup> que procesar el archivo dos veces (mi primera propuesta) sea menos costoso que procesarlo de una vez con alojado y realojado de memoria.

---

1. Dependería del tamaño del archivo y la cantidad de datos a procesar.